# Typescript - Typing serialize promises function

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to write a wrapper for arbitrary promise-returning functions that makes any call wait for the previous ones to finish.

The JavaScript implementation is below but I'm struggle to write the types for the typescript implementation. How can I type the `fn` parameter as a generic promise returning function?

```js
function serializePromises(fn) {
  // This works as our promise queue
  let last = Promise.resolve();
  return function (...args) {
    // Catch is necessary here — otherwise a rejection in a promise will
    // break the serializer forever
    last = last.catch(() => {}).then(() => fn(...args));
    return last;
  }
}
```

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mAvg8W) work for your needs? If so, I can write up an answer; if not, please let me know what use cases are unmet (preferably with an [edit] that demonstrates it via code examples)

Comment: I'm questioning you swallowing the exceptions via that empty `.catch()`. Those ought to be aggregated somewhere, or they really should let the whole chain fail. After all, in synchronous code, an exception would exit the current try block or function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use two generic type params on your function, like this

```js
function serializePromises<Args extends unknown[], R extends unknown>(fn: (...args: Args) => Promise<R>) {
  // This works as our promise queue
  let last = Promise.resolve<null | R>(null);
  
  return function (...args: Args) {
    // Catch is necessary here — otherwise a rejection in a promise will
    // break the serializer forever
    last = last.catch(() => null).then(() => fn(...args));
    return last;
  }
}
```

Returning `null` instead of just leting it be `undefined` is just a recomendation of mine.

[Here's a working playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.0-beta#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-bUnfKlar1dwuWKovpCsUYATA-09ohqOUAKyNgDUHZgxsTKbTGh7DMuTLjYBlqAMODgDBjXiAA)

Answer (score 0):

The following will work nicely but you may notice a couple casts as it is not possible to accurately type `let last = Promise.resolve()` due to it resolving without a value initially.

```js
function serializePromises<TArgs extends Array<unknown>, TReturn extends Promise<unknown>>(fn: (...args: TArgs) => TReturn): (...args: TArgs) => TReturn {
  // This works as our promise queue
  let last: Promise<any> = Promise.resolve();
  return function (...args: TArgs) {
    // Catch is necessary here — otherwise a rejection in a promise will
    // break the serializer forever
    last = last.catch(() => {}).then(() => fn(...args));
    return last as TReturn;
  }
}
```

Comment: Actually, it resolves to `undefined` initially, so you can type `last` as `Promise<TReturn | undefined>`, although I think resolving to `null` in this case would be a better choice.